# Inheritance (IS-A) vs. Composition (HAS-A) Relationship in java

Tags: java

## Inheritance (IS-A) vs. Composition (HAS-A) Relationship

please someone explaine what is **Inheritance (IS-A & HAS)**relationship in java

Comment: If you type composition vs. inheritance into google you'll find a lot of existing articles written about this. The chance that whoever answers this question will write a better explanation than all the ones already out there is very low

Answer (score 5):

**Inheritance**: `Dog` 'is an' `Animal`. In Java this is done by the `extends` keyword.

---

**Composition**: `Dog` 'has' `Eyes`. In Java this is done by having Dog an instance object of Eye.